# Getting rows filtered by most recent time mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question of a complex query and I don't know how to write it.
I have the next table:

```
+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
|id_incidencia  | id_alarma | idaction | concat(fecha, ' ', hora) |
+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
| 18488         |      551  |        1 | 2016-08-29 14:55:47      |
| 18491         |      551  |        7 | 2016-08-29 15:02:47      |
| 18493         |      551  |        6 | 2016-08-29 15:37:39      |
| 18495         |      551  |        7 | 2016-08-29 15:41:27      |
| 19263         |      551  |        6 | 2016-09-16 15:17:27      |
| 19429         |      5151 |        5 | 2016-09-19 09:01:17      |
| 19447         |      5151 |        5 | 2016-09-19 09:25:23      |
| 19500         |      5151 |        5 | 2016-09-20 09:38:11      |
| 19532         |      5151 |        5 | 2016-09-23 15:02:50      |
| 19526         |      5151 |        6 | 2016-09-23 11:23:27      |
| 19528         |      5151 |        6 | 2016-09-23 11:28:01      |
| 19527         |      5151 |        7 | 2016-09-23 11:25:18      |
| 19529         |      5151 |        7 | 2016-09-23 11:28:08      |
+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I'd like to have the next result from a query:

```
idaction | id_alarma | datetime
---------+-----------+--------- 
7        |    551    | 2016-08-29 15:41:27 
7        |    5151   | 2016-09-23 11:28:08
```

That's means that I want for each group of `id_alarma` value, I want to get the last row with the most recently time and it's value of `idaction`. The problem is that when I perform the next query, the value in `idaction` is not the same that match with the datetime field.

The query that I mention is:

```
SELECT     a.id, 
           nia.idaction, 
           MAX(CONCAT(nia.fecha, ' ', nia.hora)) 
FROM       nectar_incidencias_alarma nia 
INNER JOIN alarmas a 
        ON a.id=nia.id_alarma 
WHERE      nia.idaction IN (6,7) 
GROUP BY   a.id
```

Comment: The query that I mention is: SELECT a.id, nia.idaction, MAX(CONCAT(nia.fecha, ' ', nia.hora)) FROM nectar_incidencias_alarma nia INNER JOIN alarmas a ON a.id=nia.id_alarma WHERE nia.idaction IN (6,7) GROUP BY a.id

Comment: But 551|6 is more recent than 551|7 ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
select * from (
select * from (
SELECT     a.id, 
           nia.idaction grp_is, 
           MAX(CONCAT(nia.fecha, ' ', nia.hora)) time_is
FROM       nectar_incidencias_alarma nia 
INNER JOIN alarmas a 
        ON a.id=nia.id_alarma 
WHERE      nia.idaction IN (6,7) 
GROUP BY   a.id
) tab1
order by tab1.time_is desc) tab2
group by tab2.grp_is
```

Comment: It doesn't works, it's still appaering duplicated rows for each a.id value

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the correct value of *idaction*, you could use `group_concat` in combination with `substring_index`. Note that you don't really need to join the table *alarmas*, as you have all you need in *nectar_incidencias_alarma*:

```
SELECT     id_alarma,
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(idaction 
                           ORDER BY CONCAT(fecha, ' ', hora) DESC), ',', 1)+0 id_action,
           MAX(CONCAT(fecha, ' ', hora)) 
FROM       nectar_incidencias_alarma
WHERE      idaction IN (6,7) 
GROUP BY   id_alarma
```